# SocketIO- Object key with null values not showing in client

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, netty-socketio

I'm trying to send a message with an object from the server to the client side socket event, but when I received the message in the client side, all keys with null values are not showing from the result. I'm using `NettySocketIO` by the way in the server side.

Server Side:

```
@Override
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000, initialDelay = 5000)
public void scheduledFindAllOrders() {
   SocketMessage message = new SocketMessage();
   List<Order> orders = this.repository.findAll();
   
   message.setSender("SYSTEM");
   message.setReceiver("ALL");
   message.setMessage("Lis of orders.");
   message.setData(orders);

   //send to all clients
   this.server.getBroadcastOperations().sendEvent("orders", message);
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = TABLES.ORDER)
public class Order {
   
   @Id
   private Integer id;

   private Integer transporterId;
......other keys
```

Client Side:

```
//socket-io v 2.2.0 
const socket = io('http://localhost:8080', {
    transports: ['polling', 'websocket']
});

socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Connected');
});

socket.on('orders', function (data) {
    console.log('Received message', data);
});
```

I was expecting to get something like this

```
[{id: 1, transporterId: 2}, {id:2, transporterId: null}]
```

Instead I received this

```
[{id: 1, transporterId: 2}, {id:2}]
```

Is it a default in SocketIO client to strip away all object keys with null values? And if so is there any ways around this?

Comment: Did you get any solution? change configuration socket server

Comment: @Harish.bazee Kinda, what I did was create a util class that converts the message to json string using jackson objectmapper, then in the client side I just parse it.

Answer (score 0):

```
conf.setJsonSupport(new JacksonJsonSupport() {
    {
                      super.objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS);

    }
   });
```

here conf is Configuration for web sockets